# Can't use Mousewheel scroll on a Worksheet after running a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I created an interview questoinaire using VBA which automatically generates a list of interview questions based on criteria selected.

The selection and list of questions are all done via userforms and a listbox, the VBA behind it eventually generates a worksheet based off a hidden template which I have stored as very hidden.

At the end of the script when it generates the template out of a new workbook, it works out fine but I noticed I cannot scroll through the workbook properly as my mouse wheel is disabled.  The manual solution is to hit the STOP button on the VBA code, but I don't understand what is causing this hiccup to occur in the first place.

The code which generates the form is below, has anybody come across this problem before where workbooks stop responding, or the mouse wheel stops unless the stop button in the VBA window is clicked?

Code

```
Sub PopulateForm()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, WS4 As Worksheet
Dim newbook As Workbook

DoEvents

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Interview Questions")
Set ws3 = WB.Worksheets("Config")
Set WS4 = WB.Worksheets("Questions")


If WS.Visible = xlSheetHidden Or WS.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
WS.Visible = xlSheetVisible
End If

If ws3.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
ws3.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End If

If WS4.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
WS4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End If

Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
WS.Copy Before:=newbook.Sheets(1)

newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete

newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(103, 3).Copy
newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(103, 3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(110, 3).Copy
newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(110, 3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(117, 3).Copy
newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(117, 3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(124, 3).Copy
newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(124, 3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(131, 3).Copy
newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(131, 3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(138, 3).Copy
newbook.Sheets(1).Cells(138, 3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)


Call CleanUp.FormClose


newbook.Activate - **Mouse wheel stops here**
End Sub



Sub FormClose()
'Declare Variables
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim Config As Worksheet, Questions As Worksheet, Generator As Worksheet
Dim objLoop As Object

'Set Objects to Variables
Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook
Set Config = WB1.Worksheets("Config")
Set Questions = WB1.Worksheets("Questions")
Set Generator = WB1.Worksheets("Interview Question Generator")
Set InterviewQuestions = WB1.Worksheets("Interview Questions")

'Make configuration sheets very hidden
If Config.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
   Config.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End If

If Questions.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
   Questions.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End If

If InterviewQuestions.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
   InterviewQuestions.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End If

For Each objLoop In VBA.UserForms
    If TypeOf objLoop Is UserForm Then
       Unload objLoop
    End If
Next objLoop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

DoEvents

Generator.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll while the userform is active you must display it modelessly. From the Excel Help file:

"When a UserForm is modal, the user must respond before using any other part of the application."

Comment: Thank you, I now understand that part, but I would have thought the forms should have been unloaded in the Formclose() subroutine where objloop looks for active userforms and unloads them